# Python, BeautifulSoup, re: How to convert extracted texts to dictionary from web?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, beautifulsoup, urllib

I made a script using BeautifulSoup to extract a certain information from the web. The only problem is that I don't know how to convert the results to dictionary and if I do the code will be like a spaghetti. I am not sure if this code I wrote is acceptable to be Pythonic. The last item `Species` should be Binomial nomenclature like "Lycaon pictus" while strings after "pictus" should be ignored. Need some assistance.

#### script

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "https://www.itis.gov/servlet/SingleRpt/SingleRpt?search_topic=TSN&search_value=183833#null"
page = urlopen(Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
results = soup.findAll('tr')
for result in results:
    text = result.get_text().strip()
    pattern = r"^(Kingdom|Phylum|Division|Class|Order|Family|Genus|Species)[\w]+"
    if re.match(pattern, text):
        res = text.split('\n', 1)[0].strip()
        print(res)
```

---

#### output from script

```
KingdomAnimalia
PhylumChordata
ClassMammalia Linnaeus, 1758
OrderCarnivora Bowdich, 1821
FamilyCanidae Fischer, 1817
GenusLycaon Brookes, 1827
SpeciesLycaon pictus (Temminck, 1820) – African hunting dog, African Wild Dog, Painted Hunting Dog
```

---

#### expected result

```
{
    'Kingdom': 'Animalia',
    'Phylum': 'Chordata',
    'Class': 'Mammalia',
    'Order': 'Carnivora',
    'Family': 'Canidae',
    'Genus': 'Lycaon',
    'Species': 'Lycaon pictus'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific example given, this works:

```
...
results = soup.findAll('tr')
my_dict = {}
for result in results:
    text = result.get_text().strip()
    pattern = r"^(Kingdom|Phylum|Division|Class|Order|Family|Genus|Species)[\w]+"
    if re.match(pattern, text):
        res = text.split('\n', 1)[0].strip()
        pieces = re.findall(r'[A-Z][ a-z]*', res)
        my_dict[pieces[0]] = pieces[1]
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Kingdom': 'Animalia', 'Phylum': 'Chordata', 'Class': 'Mammalia',
 'Order': 'Carnivora', 'Family': 'Canidae', 'Genus': 'Lycaon',
 'Species': 'Lycaon pictus'}
```

This relies heavily on the exact formatting given in the example above. For example, if the website had `'Lycaon Pictus'` with a captial `'P'` for the `'Species'`, then the corresponding entry in the dictionary would be just `'Lycaon'` instead of `'Lycaon Pictus'`.

Comment: I am confused with `[A-Z][ a-z]*` a while ago, but I understand the logic behind the pattern with the help of [regex tester](https://regex101.com/). I should study more on regex. This is a lot of help. Thanks for the patience buddy.

Answer (score 1):

"result" here is someting like

```
<td align="left" class="body" width="2%"> </td>
<td align="left" class="body" valign="top" width="24%">Kingdom</td>
<td class="datafield" valign="top" width="71%"><a href="SingleRpt?search_topic=TSN&amp;search_value=202423">Animalia</a> 
 – Animal, animaux, animals</td>
<td class="body" width="5%"> </td>
```

When you use .get_text() on it, it turns to

```
'\xa0KingdomAnimalia\xa0\n – Animal, animaux, animals\n\xa0'
```

So when matching, you should use your old 'result' and split the columns up. For example:

```
if re.match(pattern, text)) :
    pieces = result.findAll('td')
```

and then use those pieces to find your information, for example

```
for p in pieces:
    print(p.get_text())
```

Of course, you cannot expect it to return dictionary, when you are working with strings and are not making-mapping one in the first place. Thus you should make one before starting for-loop, let's call it `dictionary`

```
if re.match(pattern, text):
    p = result.findAll('td')
    rank = p[1].get_text().strip()
    taxon = p[2].get_text().split('\xa0')[0]
    dictionary[rank] = taxon
```

This would get you the dictionary you are looking for